# facet vs groupby to retrieve a list of unique items in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have two pretty large solr tables, about 36,000,000 records in each, running on solr cloud v4.10.

I am trying to execute a query that will return to me all unique/distinct values given a few variables.

For example, trying to grab all unique `first_name` values within the country `USA`.  My queries are taking upwards of 90-150 seconds, which is definitely not useable, and I'm wondering if I'm going about this wrong.

I've tried solr facets as well as solr groupby, but both of these methods are crazy long.  I could use solr terms, but I haven't figured out a way to use terms WITH another `&fq`, so I'm left with two options right now:

**Using Facet Search**

```
/solr/a/select?q=country:USA&fq=year_born:[2015+TO+*]
&rows=0&facet=on&facet.limit=-1&facet.field=first_name&wt=json&indent=true
```

**Using Groupby Search**

```
/solr/a/select?q=country:USA&fl=first_name&fq=year_born:[2015+TO+*]
&group=true&group.limit=1&group.field=first_name&rows=1000000&wt=json&indent=true
```

**Using Terms**

I can get back unique `first_name` fields that exist in the table, but I have no way of saying *only show me first_names **within** the USA*, so as far as I can tell, terms cannot be used for what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying everything I can to limit the number of records that come back in either the `facet` or the `groupby` search by putting a year limit on it (give me 1 year instead of 25 years,) but the query is still too taxing.

Am I missing out on some particular solr function that does what I'm trying to do?  I need ALL results returned to me - that is the kicker - I cannot limit it at 50 or 5000 results, so at the end of the day, my output looks something like this:

```
john
bob
mike
tim
robert
dave
```

The # of occurrences is not important to me

Comment: I recommend using facets. Can you try facet.method=enum ? It uses a different faceting algorithm, which may help. Is the first query slow (uncached)? Or are all queries slow (even cached)?

Comment: Let me have a go with `facet.method=enum` - cached or uncached the result is incredibly slow - I think there's just too much data to do what I'm trying to do with facets or groupby

Comment: Is your RAM sufficient? Without caching Solr is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case is that all your documents have country:USA and that all first names are unique. To ensure the correct result, *all* results (meaning 36 million) from each node must be returned to the caller and merged there. In Solr 4.x, that means constructing potentially huge structures and sending them.

In Solr 5.x, you can use streaming. It does not change the worst-case scenario, but you avoid the memory overhead and the results starts trickling in with very little delay: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions

Using JSON Faceting in Solr 5.3+, you can get an approximate of unique values across shards very efficiently, but it is still experimental: http://yonik.com/solr-facet-functions/

Comment: Yeah, bummer - I was reading up a lot on yonik's site until I realized JSON Faceting was introduced in a later version and I cannot upgrade past 4.x.  I will look into this still.  Thanks!